# Cron Job, call url with wget

Tags: cron, wget

I have added this command line in my /etc/crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://IP:8080/auctions/updateStatus
```

It doesn't work, what's wrong with it?
The link is correct, it's a redirect to a simple java controller.

Comment: Cron has log file .... check the log at hh:mm:01 per your tab

Comment: As cron jobs are executed in a particular environment maybe you should try to call wget using the full path (i.e. /usr/bin/wget)

Comment: In the logs file, the command doesn't appear.
I tried with * * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://IP:8080/auctions/updateStatus but nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to run the command from the command line? If that url performs a redirect to a controller you should try executing wget with the option -r for Recursive Retrieval http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options

Comment: From command line it works. With -r doens't work.
After changes crontab file, have I to do something to keep the change?

Comment: You should update your question with more information. Do you want to download anything from that url? or Do you want to just fire an script? How do you know it isn't working?...

Comment: The only function for the command is call that url, I know that it doesn't work because there is no changes, while when I run the command from the shell I can see the changes in my DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error found, I forgot to insert the user who run the command (root)

Wrong:

```
* * * * * wget -r http://«IP_SERVER»:8080/auctions/updateStatus
```

Right:

```
* * * * * root wget -r http://«IP_SERVER»:8080/auctions/updateStatus
```